# In AWS once AMI is registered, can I delete this files from S3?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have registered a new AMI (instance-store AMI) so I bundled, upload the bundle and registered. So my question is, could I delete this files from S3? or I have to leave this files to get my AMI work for my new intances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must leave the image and manifest files in S3 for the AMI to work.

Amazon creates cached copies of the AMI if it is frequently used, so it might not break right away if you clear out S3 and test it, but it will cause problems eventually.

That said, I recommend using EBS boot AMIs instead of S3 based instance-store. EC2 won't even let you delete the EBS snapshot that stores the EBS boot AMI.

Comment: Thanks Eric, you're right in your opinion, but I've been in Amazon AWS workshop last week and they recommend me to use instance-store instances to get better performance and just for instances that could be in a autoscale group. My question is I really don't need the ebs volume once the autoscaller decide to shutdown, for this reason I think instance-store could be better and cheaper, am I right? Thanks! and really great blog ;)

Comment: enedebe: In my experience, it's a rare situation where the benefits of instance-store outweigh the many benefits of EBS boot.  I generally recommend you try EBS boot and only switch if you are having specific problems that require you to run instance-store.  Note that EBS boot still have ephemeral disk if you find it performs better for your particular situation.

Comment: enedebe: It's similar to warnings of over-engineering. I obviously can't answer for you but a question to ask is, are your ASGs being leveraged to such a degree that ephemeral stores will provide material impact to the performance of your stack? For many places it's a "no", but maybe for you it's "yes". You can always test and benchmark.

Comment: Eric the last part of your answer is not true. The GUI console did not previously allow it but you could always delete the EBS snapshot via the CLI or API. Currently the console does give you an option to remove the snapshot when deregistering an AMI

Comment: @DefionsCode: This question and answer are in the context of deleting the image storage behind an active, registered AMI. It can be done with S3-based instance store AMI, and it breaks the AMI. It cannot be done with EBS-backed AMI, and that is a good thing.